# Add column in observer for controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_permissions_user_roleGrid

Tags: event-observer, adminhtml, grid

I've created observer for  controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_permissions_user_roleGrid event, that is called on AJAX when filtering permission user grid. Problem is that I can't add custom column (with renderer) - how to get grid object from Varien_Event_Observer $observer?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about when using ajax but I think the event `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before` maybe a better option. This event will give you the block and then you can simply call add column directly to it.

You can then get the block and validate the type and then call add column.

```
$block = $observer->getBlock();
if (!isset($block)) {
    return $this;
}
if ($block->getType() == 'the_type/you_need') {
    $block->addColumnAfter('your_column', array(
        'header'    => 'Your Column',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'index'     => 'your_column',
    ), 'column_to_go_after');
}
```